# npm library does not show content - Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

With Vue.js I'm using the VueGoodTable library to have a table.
Let me start by saying this is my first experience with Vue.
I created my own component called VueTable.vue and defined it as follows:

```
<script>
import { VueGoodTable } from 'vue-good-table'
import 'vue-good-table/dist/vue-good-table.css'
const columns = [
  {
    label: 'Name',
    field: 'name'
  },
  {
    label: 'Age',
    field: 'age'
  },
  {
    label: 'Created On',
    field: 'createdAt'
  },
  {
    label: 'Percent',
    field: 'score'
  }
]
const rows = [
  { id: 1, name: 'John', age: 20, createdAt: '', score: 0.03343 },
  { id: 2, name: 'Jane', age: 24, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 },
  { id: 3, name: 'Susan', age: 16, createdAt: '2011-10-30', score: 0.03343 },
  { id: 4, name: 'Chris', age: 55, createdAt: '2011-10-11', score: 0.03343 },
  { id: 5, name: 'Dan', age: 40, createdAt: '2011-10-21', score: 0.03343 },
  { id: 6, name: 'John', age: 20, createdAt: '2011-10-31', score: 0.03343 }
]
export default {
  // props: ['valore1', 'valore2'],
  components: { VueGoodTable },
  data() {
    return {
      rows,
      columns
    }
  }
  // mounted() {
  //   console.log('PROPS 1', this.valore1)
  //   console.log('PROPS 2', this.valore2)
  // }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="vueTable">
    <vue-good-table :columns="columns" :rows="rows" />
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
div {
  z-index: 1000;
  background-color: rgb(223, 226, 131);
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
}
</style>
```

This is my App.vue:

```
<script setup>
import VueTable from './components/VueTable.vue'
const ciao = 'Hello man'
const prova = 'Questa è una prova'
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <VueTable />
  </div>
</template>
```

I can't see the table on the screen, in the console I have no errors and in the DOM the vue-good-table tag with dimensions 0x0 is positioned as follows:

```
<vuegoodtable columns="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]" rows="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"></vuegoodtable>
```

Can you tell me if I'm doing something wrong? Thank you

Comment: You imported the library but You didn't include it -  https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table#installing (`/* add to component */
components: {
  VueGoodTable,
}`)

Comment: @Vucko Done, but it doesn't work, I edited the post with the updated code!

Comment: The library isn't compatible with your version of Vue.  It's for Vue 2 only.  There is a note on the [github page](https://github.com/xaksis/vue-good-table#vue-good-table) about a Vue 3 version that is a work-in-progress.  You can try using that version or find an alternative library